# Changing Data Shape in Excel

Tags: excel

I have a column (or row) comprised of 11 rows (columns):

```
1
2
3
4
a
b
c
5
6
7
8
```

I want to reference this column/row in another sheet but I only want it to have numerical values AND I want it to have a minimum shape.  Meaning I want it to come out as:

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
```

with no spaces or other values comprising 8 rows.  This also needs to dynamically adjust to whatever amount of numbers are present.

In python, I would just create a list with an IF statement, append, and print the list but this specific project is forcing me to use Excel.

Can this be done easily in Excel?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use following formula to do that.

```
=INDEX($A$1:$A$11,AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW($A$1:$A$11)/ISNUMBER($A$1:$A$11),ROW(1:1)))
```

[image]